# Square retrofit server mock for testing

Tags: android, testing, mocking, retrofit, mockwebserver

What's the best way to mock a server for testing when using the [square retrofit framework](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Potential ways:

1. Create a new retrofit [client](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/Client.java) and set it in the RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(). This involves parsing the Request object and returning the json as a Response object.
2. Implement this annotated interface as a mock class and use that in place of the version provided by RestAdapter.create() (wont test gson serialisation)
3. ?

Ideally I want to have the mocked server provide json responses so I can test the gson serialisation at the same time.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JakeWharton, what's the purpose of `square-oss`?  It seems redundant given `retrofit`.

Comment: @Alec Holmes: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I decided to try method 1 as follows

```
public class MockClient implements Client {

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.getUrl());

        Log.d("MOCK SERVER", "fetching uri: " + uri.toString());

        String responseString = "";

        if(uri.getPath().equals("/path/of/interest")) {
            responseString = "JSON STRING HERE";
        } else {
            responseString = "OTHER JSON RESPONSE STRING";
        }

        return new Response(request.getUrl(), 200, "nothing", Collections.EMPTY_LIST, new TypedByteArray("application/json", responseString.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

And using it by:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
builder.setClient(new MockClient());
```

It works well and allows you to test your json strings without having to contact the real server!

Comment: I've updated the Response constructor used as the old one was deprecated, which was throwing an `IllegalArgumentException url == null` with Retrofit 1.4.1.

Comment: Also need to add an endpoint to the builder: `builder.setEndpoint("http://mockserver.com").setClient(new MockClient());`

Comment: I have extended the mock client above to fetch the response from a file in asset folder depending on the URL request.

Comment: Retrofit 2 now uses OkHttpClient for the client layer, and this code does not work. ¿Any idea how to make an OkHttpClient mock? Probably it is all about extending and overriding it, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Can you update your answer based on Retrofit2 as well? thanks

Comment: @alec-holmes In retrofit2 library they've made a Response class final, so we can't return custom Response object. Is there any workaround on this?
Here is my full question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034404/unit-testing-custom-call-class-for-retrofit2-request-reponse-has-private-acces

Answer (score 112):

### Mock Retrofit 2.0 Requests for Testing

As the old mechanisms like creating `MockClient` class and implementing it from `Client` are not working anymore with Retrofit 2.0, here I describe a new way of doing that. All what you need to do now is to **add your custom interceptors for OkHttpClient like it is shown below**. `FakeInterceptor` class just overrides `intercept` method and in the case if application is in `DEBUG` mode return given JSON.

#### RestClient.java

```
public final class RestClient {

    private static IRestService mRestService = null;

    public static IRestService getClient() {
        if(mRestService == null) {
            final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            // ***YOUR CUSTOM INTERCEPTOR GOES HERE***
            client.interceptors().add(new FakeInterceptor());

            final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            // Using custom Jackson Converter to parse JSON
                            // Add dependencies:
                            // com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                            // Endpoint
                    .baseUrl(IRestService.ENDPOINT)
                    .client(client)
                    .build();

            mRestService = retrofit.create(IRestService.class);
        }
        return mRestService;
    }
}
```

#### IRestService.java

```
public interface IRestService {

    String ENDPOINT = "http://www.vavian.com/";

    @GET("/")
    Call<Teacher> getTeacherById(@Query("id") final String id);
}
```

#### FakeInterceptor.java

```
public class FakeInterceptor implements Interceptor { 
    // FAKE RESPONSES.
    private final static String TEACHER_ID_1 = "{\"id\":1,\"age\":28,\"name\":\"Victor Apoyan\"}";
    private final static String TEACHER_ID_2 = "{\"id\":1,\"age\":16,\"name\":\"Tovmas Apoyan\"}";

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = null;
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            String responseString;
            // Get Request URI.
            final URI uri = chain.request().url().uri();
            // Get Query String.
            final String query = uri.getQuery();
            // Parse the Query String.
            final String[] parsedQuery = query.split("=");
            if(parsedQuery[0].equalsIgnoreCase("id") && parsedQuery[1].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                responseString = TEACHER_ID_1;
            }
            else if(parsedQuery[0].equalsIgnoreCase("id") && parsedQuery[1].equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
                responseString = TEACHER_ID_2;
            }
            else {
                responseString = "";
            }

            response = new Response.Builder()
                    .code(200)
                    .message(responseString)
                    .request(chain.request())
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), responseString.getBytes()))
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .build();
        }
        else {
            response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Source code of project on [GitHub](https://github.com/vapoyan/Mock-Response-In-Retrofit-2.0)

Comment: To avoid UnsupportedOperationException use OkHttpClient.Builder.

final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new FakeInterceptor())
                .build();

Comment: Two problems I have: 1- There is no `uri()` under `chain.request().uri()` (I fixed this by `String url = chain.request().url().toString();` as my case different). 2- I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: network interceptor my.package.name.FakeInterceptor must call proceed() exactly once`. I have added this to `addNetworkInterceptor()` rather than `addInterceptor()`.

Comment: use chain.request().url().uri();

Comment: How I can mock 401 error to test httpClient.authenticator method? by just putting code "401" authenticate method do not calls. how I can handle this?

Comment: I have taken the fake interceptor approach to mocking web apis to the next level and published a little library for that to make it even easier and more convenient. See  https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer

Answer (score 22):

Testing JSON deserialization to your objects (presumably with `TypeAdapters`?) seems like a separate problem that require separate unit tests.

I use version 2 personally. It affords type-safe, refactor-friendly code that can be easily debugged and altered. After all, what good is declaring your API as interfaces if you aren't creating alternate versions of them for testing! Polymorphism for the win.

Another option is using a Java `Proxy`. This is actually how Retrofit (currently) implements its underlying HTTP interaction. This will admittedly require more work, but would allow for much more dynamic mocks.

Comment: This is also my preferred way, too. It's a lot simpler to debug as stated above then having to deal so directly with response body. 

@alec If you want to test the GSON serialization, generate/read-in a json string and use a gson object to deserialize. Under the head I believe that's what Retrofit does anyway.

Comment: @JakeWharton Could you provide a short example of what this would like? I'm having trouble visualizing this... Thanks!

Comment: @uncle_tex Have a look onto https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/src/internalDebug/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/api/MockGithubService.java

Answer (score 10):

You can also use something like Webservermock from Squareup! --> https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Comment: Yes mockwebserver is great! I have built a small library on top of it to make mocking apis even easier: [Mockinizer](https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer)

Answer (score 8):

I am a big fan of [Apiary.io](http://apiary.io) for a mocking an API before moving to a real server.

You could also use flat .json files and read them from the file system.

You could also use publicly accessible API's like Twitter, Flickr, etc.

Here are some other great resources about Retrofit.

Slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/12Eb8OPI0PDisCjWne9-0qlXvp_-R4HmqVCjigOIgwfY/edit#slide=id.p

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtM06W51pPw&feature=g-user-u

Example Project: https://github.com/dustin-graham/ucad_twitter_retrofit_sample

Answer (score 7):

[Mockery](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/Mockery) (disclaimer: I’m the author) was designed just for this exactly task.

Mockery is a mocking/testing library focused on validating networking layers with built-in support for Retrofit. It auto-generates JUnit tests based on the specs of a given Api. The idea is not to have to write manually any test; neither implementing interfaces for mocking server responses.

Answer (score 7):

1. First,create your Retrofit interface.

   ```
   public interface LifeKitServerService {
       /**
        * query event list from server,convert Retrofit's Call to RxJava's Observerable
        *
        * @return Observable<HttpResult<List<Event>>> event list from server,and it has been convert to Obseverable
        */
       @GET("api/event")
       Observable<HttpResult<List<Event>>> getEventList();
   }
   ```
2. Your Requester in follow:

   ```
   public final class HomeDataRequester {
       public static final String TAG = HomeDataRequester.class.getSimpleName();
       public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = BuildConfig.DATA_SERVER_ADDR + "/";
       private LifeKitServerService mServerService;

       private HomeDataRequester() {
           OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                   //using okhttp3 interceptor fake response.
                   .addInterceptor(new MockHomeDataInterceptor())
                   .build();

           Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .client(okHttpClient)
                   .baseUrl(SERVER_ADDRESS)
                   .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                   .build();

           //using okhttp3 inteception to fake response.
           mServerService = retrofit.create(LifeKitServerService.class);

           //Second choice,use MockRetrofit to fake data.
           //NetworkBehavior behavior = NetworkBehavior.create();
           //MockRetrofit mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit)
           //        .networkBehavior(behavior)
           //        .build();
           //mServerService = new MockLifeKitServerService(
           //                    mockRetrofit.create(LifeKitServerService.class));
       }

       public static HomeDataRequester getInstance() {
           return InstanceHolder.sInstance;
       }

       public void getEventList(Subscriber<HttpResult<List<Event>>> subscriber) {
           mServerService.getEventList()
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                   .subscribe(subscriber);
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you using the second choice(use Retrofit interface to Mock server data),you need to MockRetrofit,use code follow:

   ```
   public final class MockLifeKitServerService implements LifeKitServerService {
   public static final String TAG = MockLifeKitServerService.class.getSimpleName();
   private BehaviorDelegate<LifeKitServerService> mDelegate;
   private Gson mGson = new Gson();

   public MockLifeKitServerService(BehaviorDelegate<LifeKitServerService> delegate) {
       mDelegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public Observable<HttpResult<List<Event>>> getEventList() {
       List<Event> eventList = MockDataGenerator.generateEventList();
       HttpResult<List<Event>> httpResult = new HttpResult<>();
       httpResult.setCode(200);
       httpResult.setData(eventList);

       LogUtil.json(TAG, mGson.toJson(httpResult));

       String text = MockDataGenerator.getMockDataFromJsonFile("server/EventList.json");
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
           text = mGson.toJson(httpResult);
       }
       LogUtil.d(TAG, "Text:\n" + text);

       text = mGson.toJson(httpResult);

       return mDelegate.returningResponse(text).getEventList();
   }
   ```

4.My data is from asset file(Asset/server/EventList.json),this file content is:

```
    {
      "code": 200,
      "data": [
        {
          "uuid": "e4beb3c8-3468-11e6-a07d-005056a05722",
          "title": "title",
          "image": "http://image.jpg",
          "goal": 1500000,
          "current": 51233,
          "hot": true,
          "completed": false,
          "createdAt": "2016-06-15T04:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
```

5.If you are using okhttp3 interceptor,you need to self-defined interceptor,like this:

```
public final class MockHomeDataInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    public static final String TAG = MockHomeDataInterceptor.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = null;

        String path = chain.request().url().uri().getPath();
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "intercept: path=" + path);

        response = interceptRequestWhenDebug(chain, path);
        if (null == response) {
            LogUtil.i(TAG, "intercept: null == response");
            response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private Response interceptRequestWhenDebug(Chain chain, String path) {
        Response response = null;
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (path.equalsIgnoreCase("/api/event")) {
                //get event list
                response = getMockEventListResponse(request);
            }
    }

    private Response getMockEventListResponse(Request request) {
        Response response;

        String data = MockDataGenerator.getMockDataFromJsonFile("server/EventList.json");
        response = getHttpSuccessResponse(request, data);
        return response;
    }

    private Response getHttpSuccessResponse(Request request, String dataJson) {
        Response response;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dataJson)) {
            LogUtil.w(TAG, "getHttpSuccessResponse: dataJson is empty!");
            response = new Response.Builder()
                    .code(500)
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
                    .request(request)
                    //protocol&request be set,otherwise will be exception.
                    .build();
        } else {
            response = new Response.Builder()
                    .code(200)
                    .message(dataJson)
                    .request(request)
                    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), dataJson))
                    .build();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

6.Finally,you can request your server with code:

```
mHomeDataRequester.getEventList(new Subscriber<HttpResult<List<Event>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        LogUtil.e(TAG, "onError: ", e);
        if (mView != null) {
            mView.onEventListLoadFailed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(HttpResult<List<Event>> httpResult) {
        //Your json result will be convert by Gson and return in here!!!
    });
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please explain what is "MockDataGenerator"

Comment: @MdImranChoudhury it just a a class that i wrote to load json file.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the answer by @Alec, I have extended the mock client to get the response directly from a text file in asset folder depending on the request URL.

Ex

```
@POST("/activate")
public void activate(@Body Request reqdata, Callback callback);
```

Here the mock client, understands that the URL being fired is activate and looks for a file named activate.txt in the assets folder.
It reads the content from assets/activate.txt file and sends it as response for the API.

Here is the extended `MockClient`

```
public class MockClient implements Client {
    Context context;

    MockClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.getUrl());

        Log.d("MOCK SERVER", "fetching uri: " + uri.toString());

        String filename = uri.getPath();
        filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split("?")[0];

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename.toLowerCase() + ".txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String responseString = new String(buffer);

        return new Response(request.getUrl(), 200, "nothing", Collections.EMPTY_LIST, new TypedByteArray("application/json", responseString.getBytes()));
    }
}
```

For a detailed explanation you can checkout my blog 
http://www.cumulations.com/blogs/13/Mock-API-response-in-Retrofit-using-custom-clients

Comment: hi, When I am writing a test class using robolectric and using mock client to mock the retrofit api, it is not giving me any response. Could you guide me how to do this.

Comment: Hi @Dory make sure you have the URL ending part and the filename inside the assets folder.

For example, lets say your URL is as below ( using Reftrofit here)
 @POST("/redeemGyft")
 public void redeemGyft(@Body MposRequest reqdata, Callback<RedeemGyftResponse> callback);

then the correspodning file name in asset folder is redeemgyft.txt

Comment: I have given static file name, in my `MockClient` file, written a test class using robolectric. But I am not able to get any response from json file.

Comment: if you have kept the file inside the assets folder it should pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking api calls with Retrofit is now even easier with **[Mockinizer](https://github.com/donfuxx/Mockinizer)** which makes working with MockWebServer really straight forward:

```
import com.appham.mockinizer.RequestFilter
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse

val mocks: Map<RequestFilter, MockResponse> = mapOf(

    RequestFilter("/mocked") to MockResponse().apply {
        setResponseCode(200)
        setBody("""{"title": "Banana Mock"}""")
    },

    RequestFilter("/mockedError") to MockResponse().apply {
        setResponseCode(400)
    }

)
```

Just create a map of **RequestFilter and MockResponses** and then plug it into your OkHttpClient builder chain:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .mockinize(mocks) // <-- just plug in your custom mocks here
            .build()
```

You don't have to worry about configuring MockWebServer etc. Just add your mocks all the rest is done by Mockinizer for you.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of Mockinizer)

Answer (score 1):

#### JSONPlaceholder: Fake Online REST API for Testing and Prototyping

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

#### ReqresIn: Another Online REST API

https://reqres.in/

#### Postman mock server

If you want to test customized response payload, the above two might not suit your requirement, then you can try postman mock server.
It's quite easy to set up and flexible to define your own request and response payload.

[image]
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/intro_to_mock_servers/
https://youtu.be/shYn3Ys3ygE

Answer (score 0):

For me the custom Retrofit Client is great because of flexibility. Especially when you use any DI framework you can fast and simple turn on/off mock. I am using custom Client provided by Dagger also in unit and integration tests.

Edit:
Here you find example of mocking retrofit
https://github.com/pawelByszewski/retrofitmock