# How to test a REST client implemented using Retrofit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, retrofit

I implemented a Java client for my REST API using Retrofit. The client is a simple java app and not an Android Application. How do I write unit tests for my Java client ? Following is one of my service classes.

```
public interface CountryService {

    /**
     * Returns country list.
     * 
     * @param sortby
     *            Optional; Sorting order of list. Pass null to ignore.
     * 
     * @return Countries object with list of countries.
     * 
     * @throws SRSRetrofitException
     */

    @GET(SRSClientConstants.SLASH + SRSClientConstants.RESOURCE_COUNTRY)
    public Countries getCountries(@Query("sortby") String sortby)
            throws SRSRetrofitException;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17544751/515948).

Comment: I ended up implementing answer of that question.

Answer (score -1):

With a REST Application hosted online you just need to use GET/POST and other HTTP methods to query the service. No special construct as such is required. Try sending a HTTP Request with all the valid parameters. It should work. For more on REST [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Comment: Question is how to unit test a client written using Retrofit for a REST API. I don't understand your answer.

Comment: this might be of some help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544751/square-retrofit-server-mock-for-testing