# Using Mockito with Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit, rx-java, android-testing

I'm trying to create unit tests for my api calls(made via `Retrofit` 2.0) using `Mockito`.

This seemed to be the most popular blog on using `Mockito` with `Retrofit`.

http://mdswanson.com/blog/2013/12/16/reliable-android-http-testing-with-retrofit-and-mockito.html

Unfortunately, it uses earlier versions of `Retrofit`, and depends on the `Callbacks` and `RetrofitError`, which are discontinued from 2.0.

How do you do this with `Retrofit 2.0`?

P.S.: I'm using `RxJava` along with `retrofit`, so something that works with `RxJava` would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at OkHttp's MockWebServer and MockResponse classes?  They can do all of this without Mockito dependency...

Comment: you can create your mocked server for unit test  using intercpetor in retrofit

Answer (score 3):

on official repository of Retrofit there's an example which can be useful:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock

I've also found: https://touk.pl/blog/2014/02/26/mock-retrofit-using-dagger-and-mockito/

Here you would find this fragment:

> ## Unit Tests
>
> During develop of app, you can send requests the server all time(or
>   most of time) so it is possible to live without mocked server, it
>   sucks but is possible. Unfortunately you are not able to write good
>   tests without the mock. Below there are two unit tests. Actually they
>   do not test anything but in simple way shows how to mock `Retrofit`
>   service using `Mockito` and `Dagger`.

```
    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class EchoServiceTest {

    @Inject
    protected EchoService loginService;

    @Inject
    protected Client client;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Injector.add(new AndroidModule(), 
                     new RestServicesModule(),
                     new RestServicesMockModule(),
                     new TestModule());
        Injector.inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnOfferInAsyncMode() throws IOException {
        //given
        int expectedQuantity = 765;
        String responseContent = "{" +
                "   \"message\": \"mock message\"," +
                "   \"quantity\": \"" + expectedQuantity + "\"" +
                "}";
        mockResponseWithCodeAndContent(200, responseContent);

        //when
        EchoResponse echoResponse = loginService.getMessageAndQuantity("test", "test");

        //then
        assertThat(echoResponse.getQuantity()).isEqualTo(expectedQuantity);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnOfferInAsyncModea() throws IOException {
        //given
        int expectedQuantity = 2;
        String responseContent = "{" +
                "   \"message\": \"mock message\"," +
                "   \"quantity\": \"" + expectedQuantity + "\"" +
                "}";
        mockResponseWithCodeAndContent(200, responseContent);

        //when
        EchoResponse echoResponse = loginService.getMessageAndQuantity("test", "test");

        //then
        assertThat(echoResponse.getQuantity()).isEqualTo(expectedQuantity);
    }


    protected void mockResponseWithCodeAndContent(int httpCode, String content) throws IOException {
        Response response = createResponseWithCodeAndJson(httpCode, content);
        when(client.execute(Matchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(response);
    }

    private Response createResponseWithCodeAndJson(int responseCode, String json) {
        return new Response(responseCode, "nothing", Collections.EMPTY_LIST, new TypedByteArray("application/json", json.getBytes()));
    }
```

Read also: [Square retrofit server mock for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544751/square-retrofit-server-mock-for-testing)

Hope it help