# Unit testing, custom Call class for retrofit2 request: Reponse has private access

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, retrofit2

When I create custom Call class I can't return Response, because Response class is final. Is there any workaround for this?

```
public class TestCall implements Call<PlacesResults> {

    String fileType;
    String getPlacesJson = "getplaces.json";
    String getPlacesUpdatedJson = "getplaces_updated.json";

    public TestCall(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute() throws IOException {
        String responseString;
        InputStream is;
        if (fileType.equals(getPlacesJson)) {
            is = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getAssets().open(getPlacesJson);
        } else {
            is = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getAssets().open(getPlacesUpdatedJson);
        }

        PlacesResults placesResults= new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(is), PlacesResults.class);
        //CAN"T DO IT
        return new Response<PlacesResults>(null, placesResults, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(Callback callback) {

    }

//default methods here
//....
}
```

In my unit test class I want to use it like this:

```
Mockito.when(mockApi.getNearbyPlaces(eq("testkey"), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyInt())).thenReturn(new TestCall("getplaces.json"));
GetPlacesAction action = new GetPlacesAction(getContext().getContentResolver(), mockEventBus, mockApi, "testkey");
action.downloadPlaces();
```

My downloadPlaces() method look like:

```
public void downloadPlaces() {
    Call<PlacesResults> call = api.getNearbyPlaces(webApiKey, LocationLocator.getInstance().getLastLocation(), 500);

    PlacesResults jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        Response<PlacesResults> response = call.execute();
        Timber.d("response " + response);
        jsonResponse = response.body();
        if (jsonResponse == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Response is null");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        events.sendError(EventBus.ERROR_NO_CONNECTION);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        events.sendError(EventBus.ERROR_NO_PLACES);
        return;
    }

    //TODO: some database operations
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at retrofit2 Response class more thoroughly I've found out that there is a static method that do what I need. So, I simply changed this line:

```
return new Response<PlacesResults>(null, placesResults, null);
```

to:

```
return Response.success(placesResults);
```

Everything works now.